# Libreoffice-calc: create a new sheet from shell cmd line

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, libreoffice-calc

I would like to write several csv files into  different libreofrice-calc sheets.

In first intend I was using python / pandas to export csv data into calc files. But it takes time (several min). I realized that importing Csv data directly from calc was faster (few seconds). As a result, I expect to import a series of csv files into different calc sheet from shell cmd line. But I found no doc about that. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Interacting with LibreOffice from a python-uno shell is convenient but slow because LO must be run in listening mode. Can you run a python script from within LibreOffice (such as with [APSO](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python)), or are you limited to a non-graphical interface such as a remote terminal? If you cannot use APSO, then perhaps you will need a third-party library that can modify .ods files.

Comment: Also posted at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180813/adding-csv-data-into-libreoffice-calc-from-cmd-line.